# Powershell scripting custom object

Tags: powershell, scripting, pscustomobject

below data set is stored is text file  and first is server name, second one is date and 3rd one is the patch histroy.

```
WSUSCL02-2012

Monday, August 10, 2020 5:03:08 PM



X Status     KB          Size Title                                            
- ------     --          ---- -----                                            
2 Accepted   KB3172729  10 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
2 Accepted   KB3175024  12 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
3 Downloaded KB3172729  10 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
3 Downloaded KB3175024  12 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
4 Installed  KB3172729  10 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
4 Installed  KB3175024  12 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...



WSUSCL01-2012

Monday, August 10, 2020 5:03:01 PM



X Status     KB          Size Title                                            
- ------     --          ---- -----                                            
2 Accepted   KB2962409  50 MB Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB2962409)    
2 Accepted   KB3175024  12 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
3 Downloaded KB2962409  50 MB Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB2962409)    
3 Downloaded KB3175024  12 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
4 Installed  KB2962409  50 MB Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB2962409)    
4 Installed  KB3175024  12 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
```

Above is the data set stored in a text file and the requirement is to parse data and pick servername , date , patch  and put that data in a custom power shell object with the name of sever name, date, patch details. please help me out to do this

Comment: Can you post a bit more information - what have you tried so far? What didn't work about it?

Comment: Watching this video may help you: [Sophisitcated Techniques of Plain Text Parsing](https://youtu.be/Hkzd8spCfCU)

Comment: $data=Get-Content C:\data1.log

$alldata=$data | Foreach {

                    if ($_ -ilike "*") {Write-Output $_}

$server=$alldata | foreach {
                    
                    if ($_ -ilike "*WSUS*") {Write-Output $_}
                    
                   } 

$Patch = $alldata | foreach {

                    if ($_ -inotlike "*WSUS*") {Write-Output $_}


}


    }


 $serverdetail = $server | foreach {

    [PSCustomObject]@{    
        SERVER = $_
 
    }

   
}
through that way only i got server detail and able to put in custom object

Comment: Please do not add additional information as comment. Instead edit your question and add it there. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `switch -Regex -File` to loop over every line in the text file should do the trick.

Below code parses out **all** filds, but you can comment out any properties you donot wish in the result

```
$result = switch -Regex -File 'D:\Test\patches.txt' {
    '^[-\w]+$' { $server = $_ }
    '[AP]M$'   { $date = [datetime]::ParseExact($_, 'F', [cultureinfo]'en-US') }
    '^(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+(KB\d+)\s+(\d+\s[KM]B)\s+(.+)' {
        # create and output an object
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Server = $server
            Date   = $date
            X      = $matches[1]
            Status = $matches[2]
            KB     = $matches[3]
            Size   = $matches[4]
            Title  = $matches[5]
        }
   }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\patchresults.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output using your example file

```
Server        Date               X Status     KB        Size  Title                                            
------        ----               - ------     --        ----  -----                                            
WSUSCL02-2012 10-8-2020 17:03:08 2 Accepted   KB3172729 10 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
WSUSCL02-2012 10-8-2020 17:03:08 2 Accepted   KB3175024 12 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
WSUSCL02-2012 10-8-2020 17:03:08 3 Downloaded KB3172729 10 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
WSUSCL02-2012 10-8-2020 17:03:08 3 Downloaded KB3175024 12 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
WSUSCL02-2012 10-8-2020 17:03:08 4 Installed  KB3172729 10 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
WSUSCL02-2012 10-8-2020 17:03:08 4 Installed  KB3175024 12 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
WSUSCL01-2012 10-8-2020 17:03:01 2 Accepted   KB2962409 50 MB Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB2962409)    
WSUSCL01-2012 10-8-2020 17:03:01 2 Accepted   KB3175024 12 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
WSUSCL01-2012 10-8-2020 17:03:01 3 Downloaded KB2962409 50 MB Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB2962409)    
WSUSCL01-2012 10-8-2020 17:03:01 3 Downloaded KB3175024 12 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
WSUSCL01-2012 10-8-2020 17:03:01 4 Installed  KB2962409 50 MB Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB2962409)    
WSUSCL01-2012 10-8-2020 17:03:01 4 Installed  KB3175024 12 MB Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB...
```

<sup>P.S. my system is Dutch, so the default date format displayed is 'dd-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss'</sup>

Comment: Can we have only a single entry o f server name instead of iteration?

Comment: AUTOM01-AYEHU1:No Updates Available
AUTOM01-AYEHU2:No Updates Available
AUTOM01-AYEHU3:No Updates Available
AUTOM01-AYEHU4:No Updates Available
AUTOM01-AYEHU5:No Updates Available
AUTOM01-AYEHU6:No Updates Available
@Theo that on this data set  i have simmilar requirement but not able to get the result like  need 2 custom object with the name  (SERVERNAME, STATUS) and put data into it

Comment: @prabhat [1]  For your first comment: yes, you can group the `$result` array on the server like `$servers = $result | Group-Object Server`. [2]  As for your second comment: this is barely readable, but if I understand correctly, on that data you can do: `$result = $data  -replace ':', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData`

Comment: for the second comments how can i use this existing code to make 2 objects by using some regex  '(\D*)\s'
    '[^-]*'